# Why is git gui not respecting comment lines added by a git hook?

Tags: git

I've written a prepare-commit-msg hook that maps Team Foundation
Server workitem ID's to a Git commit message. 
(When committing, a picklist appears. Users can select one or more workitems and the
workitems are added to the commit message using a specific format.
Later on, we use git log --grep to search for specific commits
belonging to a workitem).

I'm using comments in the commit message to give additional
information to the user. For example, when the Team Foundation Server
is not available, I add the following comment to the top of the commit
message.

```
# Warning: could not access Team Foundation Server at <servername>.
```

Because the line starts with a # sign, it is not added to the actual
commit message...*when using git commit*.

If I use git gui, the above
comment appears in the git gui interface but *is* actually added to
the git commit message when committing.

Is there a specific reason that git gui is actually adding lines
starting with a # sign? I was expecting it to ignore those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git in general does not have comments in commit messages like that. What you are referring to is a specific feature of `git commit -e` which is the default if -m or -F are not used.

`git gui`, `git commit -m`, and `git commit -F` all take the commit message as exactly what was given to them.

Since you are using a prepare-commit-msg hook to add the lines, a solution would be to add a commit-msg hook that removes the lines. The commit-msg hook will be used by all commit methods.

Comment: You say that git gui takes the commit message as exactly as was given. Not in my experience. For example, try a git commit. You will see comment lines in the default commit message. Those comment lines are *not* shown when using git gui.

Comment: Because those comment lines are only added when git commit launches an editor. Its not that git gui is hiding them, they are never added to the commit message when using git gui.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies things. Thanks!